# solr: partial document update or join?

Tags: solr

i have an index of products in solr (the index is updated with DataImport from a mysql/jdbc).

the products can be available or not in some store: right now we have this model in the index (the stores are a multivalued int field)

```
{
 id:
 product_id:
 stores: [ store_id, store_id, ...] 
 ...
}
```

the `stores` field in gonna be changed very often, with an external tool that updates the solr document, changing only the value in the array.

is this the best pattern to model this in solr?
could be better to have separate documents and then join?

Answer (score 2):

depends on what is *very often* for you, it might be ok to just update the whole doc...But,  if it is going to be a problem and you wish to optimize the load due to the constant updating, you have several options:

1. [In place updates](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/updating-parts-of-documents.html) you have some constraints (how to encode the list of stores in a numeric), but would work
2. [ExternalFileField](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/working-with-external-files-and-processes.html)
3. [Nested docs](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/uploading-data-with-index-handlers.html#uploading-data-with-index-handlers)
4. Different collections and join across them as you mention

I would prefer 1 myself, more integrated with the rest of Solr than 2...3 and 4 are not a good fit imho.

Comment: In place updates require the field to be single valued, so it wouldn't fit the structure given in the question. I'd probably just go with the structure given from the OP - I think using DIH will be more of a performance issue than the document structure.

Comment: I was addressing that issue in my edit...depends on the number of stores, but it's very possible the info could be encoded in a numeric.

Comment: Querying will usually be harder if its encoded (i.e. as a bitmask) so it depends on how the field will be used as well. Do it the straight forward way and then optimize if it becomes an issue is a good plan (as you lead with).

Comment: "often" could means every few minutes (from 2 to 5). the `stores` field contains hundreds values, and is always used in every query.
'in place updates' seems complicated to me in this case. i will take a look at external file, is something new to me

Comment: of course depends on your index size, cluster resources, how many docs are changed etc, but every few minutes does not look so so bad. Do test!